# C# WPF OnDragMoveWindow preforms on just click?

Tags: c#, wpf, borderless

I created a *borderless* window in WPF. My goal is to have a window with full functionality.
Currently I have one function remaining.

When the `windowState` is **Maximized** and I click on the `titlebar`, the window is set to **minimized**. This behavior is wrong because the **windowState** should not **minimized** unless I double click or if I click or move the cursor.

This is the code I want to only execute if the cursor is moving: (*Around 10px from the start position*)

```
private void OnDragMoveWindow(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InternalWindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    {
        if (_enableDrag)
        {
            var c = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
            this.InternalWindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            this.Height = _location.Height;
            this.Width = _location.Width;
            this.Top = c.Y - (titleBar.ActualHeight / 2);
            this.Left = c.X - (_location.Width / 2);
            this.DragMove();
        }
     }
     else
     {
        this.DragMove();
     }
}
```

When I double click this code is executed:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
private void OnMaximizeWindow(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InternalWindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        this.InternalWindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    else
    {
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
        _enableDrag = false;
        this.InternalWindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

[My window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVxxK.png)

Comment: How can you click on the title bar if the window is borderless? There is no title bar.

Comment: Can you tell the source of your events ?

Comment: You should show us how you've customised your window. The usual way to remove borders would be to set windowstyle to none. Once you do that, however, there will be no titlebar. So either your description is misleading or you're doing something else. I also think you'd do better using wpf framework and comparing cursor position to the grid or panel that is the root element of content in your window.

Comment: I created my own title bar. What do you mean by the source of the my events?

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is :

```
private void OnDragMoveWindow(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount >= 2)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                var c = e.GetPosition(this);
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
            else
            {
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.DragMove();
        }
       
    }
```

The Event Source is MouseDown

```
MouseDown="OnDragMoveWindow"
```

Yours is not Working because the mousedoubleclick event is after the mouse click event. So your Window state is switching betwenn the states with one "MouseAction".

Replace my -10 constants with your prefered values.

Comment: I can't see how this is a solution? You remove every necessary lines of codes and did not even use "this.InternalWindowState"

Comment: All I want is the code in MouseLeftButtonDown="OnDragMoveWindow" only to execute if the mouse is moving, not if you just click on the "titlebar"

Comment: Why ? What is your target ? You want to move the window with the mouse ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very confusing, but if you want detect drag actions then you need to compare mouse position between mouse down, and mouse up.

- If mouse movement < 10 px then you do your click behaviour.
- If mouse movement > 10 px then you do your drag behaviour.

You can override [UIElement.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.onpreviewmouseleftbuttondown?view=netcore-3.1) and [UIElement.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.onpreviewmouseleftbuttonup?view=netcore-3.1) to capture the mouse movement during the click.